# How do I avoid cell reloading?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to disable reloading in a table view when scrolling. Now, my app gets reloaded when the user scrolls the `UITableview` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets recalled.

Code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[listingTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TripCardCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:[TripCardCell cellID]];
```

Code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TripCardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:[TripCardCell cellID]];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
```

Comment: The TableView its not reloading every time the user scrolls, it has lazy load, the table is just loading the next elements of the list and "cleaning" the ones that are no longer visible. You cannot change that, as far as I know, it is the default behavior of the table. Even that you could disable lazy loading, there is no good reason to do that, I think.

Comment: Since you have registered a nib against the cell reuse identifier `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will never return nil, so the second code snippet you have shown will never execute. What exactly do you mean by "reloaded"?  Can you describe the problem more clearly?  Can you show your entire `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by reloading? As other comment says if you are using `func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` to get an existing cell back then at most you will have N visible cells + a few more in memory at any one time.

Comment: Sounds like you might be getting confused with cell reuse, scrolling a table view should not reload the whole table.